# Are Civicon Session materials aggregated somewhere?

Tags: tutorials

I have seen session slides on slideshare and some youtube videos, and links posted on civicrm.org but wondering if there is a repository for all things civicon somewhere that is publicly available?

Comment: Bummer! I presented at that Civicon and I'd love to see the video of my session. Does anyone know if they exist somewhere still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a playlist with the [videos on Youtube for 2015](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs):

Answer (score 1):

CiviCon materials SHOULD be posted on the sessions page for the session in question.  Please keep in mind that CiviCon North America 2014 videos were never released due to quality issues, and CiviCon North America 2015 videos are currently in post-production.